# Error in PyCharm "WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes "

Tags: python, pyspark, pycharm

[PyCharm/PySpark Error]
Getting below error in PyCharm:
**WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties**
I am using PyCharm on Windows PC.

*Code:*

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
sc = SparkContext(master="local", appName="Spark Demo")
print(sc.textFile("C:\\Spark Demo.txt").first())
```

*Result*

```
20/04/29 00:22:50 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Spark Demo
```

Comment: don't take screenshots. post the text.